# Format strongly-typed element value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have property of type double in my ViewModel and I have create a TextBox for it:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DoubleProperty)
```

Is there any way to format text box value (for example, to apply some String.Format magic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could decorate your view model property with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute allowing you to specify any format:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###.###}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public double? DoubleProperty { get; set; }
```

and in your view use the `EditorFor` helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DoubleProperty)
```

Another possibility is to write a custom editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyDouble.cshtml`):

```
@model double?
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("###.###") : "")
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DoubleProperty, "MyDouble")
```

or if you don't want to explicitly specify the `MyDouble` custom editor template when calling the `EditorFor` helper you could also use the [`[UIHint]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute on your view model:

```
[UIHint("MyDouble")]
public double? DoubleProperty { get; set; }
```